# Metaio SDK getAllGeometriesFromViewportCoordinates

Tags: ios, metaio

Hi I am building an augmented reality iOS app with the Metaio SDK, and am running into some issues with the function getAllGeometriesFromViewportCoordinates. In my header (.h file), I'm calling the class constructor:

```
@interface HelloWorldViewController : MetaioSDKViewController
{
metaio::Vector3d  modelLocation;
}
```

and in my .mm file:

```
modelLocation = m_metaioSDK->getAllGeometriesFromViewportCoordinates(loc.x, loc.y, true, 3, 0);
```

The error I'm getting is "No viable overloaded '='"

Here's what the Metaio docs say about this function: http://doxygen.metaio.com/metaioSDK55/getAllGeometriesFromViewportCoordinates_1a31f4d68ef273dc05d8be5094dc25910d.html

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `getAllGeometriesFromViewportCoordinates` is

```
stlcompat::Vector < metaio::GeometryHit >
```

You're trying to assign it to a metaio::Vector3d.

Maybe you actually want to call this method? http://doxygen.metaio.com/metaioSDK55/get3DPositionFromScreenCoordinates_1ae31b85a5c22fd3392ef6186401fd6046.html